# Where to report app bugs

Tags: support, bug, status-completed, ios-app

As seen in the image bellow, the help section of the app suggest that bugs are reported to Meta Stack Overflow.

Should this be changed now to show Meta Stack Exchange in the next update, or should we still report bugs to Meta Stack Overflow?

[image: iPhone app help page]

Comment: I would guess it should be MSE.

Comment: Report bugs here; presumably the text will be altered in a future version.

Comment: And 0.1.54 points to MSE now.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You should report bugs here. The app will state this too as of the next release. Thanks for spotting this!

Answer (score 2):

You should report bugs and make feature requests on this site, Meta Stack Exchange. Meta Stack Overflow is now a 'normal' per-site meta. Since the app is a network-wide client, questions/bugs/requests about it should be posted here.