# Android app referencing users to MSO?

Tags: feature-request, status-completed, android-app

In the current version of the Android app (v1.0.31), the help page says

> Bugs or feature requests should be reported on [Meta Stack Overflow](http://meta.stackoverflow.com) and tagged **android-app**

Since the grand split happened, it looks like Meta Stack Overflow is migrating the [android-app](/questions/tagged/android-app) questions to Meta Stack Exchange. Granted, no one probably reads the help text. But should the text be updated to point people to Meta Stack Exchange?

Comment: Related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/230175/ios-app-invitation-landing-page-still-links-to-meta-stack-overflow

Comment: Also related: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/229966/where-to-report-app-bugs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fixed in version 1.0.32, thanks!